# Performance issues while recalculating ´WriteableBitmap´

Tags: c#, wpf, object, writablebitmap

Since my issue is rather uncommon and I have not a single clue what could be causing it, I will try to include every code that might have anything to do with it, stripped down to the very essentials to avoid unnecessary clutter.

Basically, I have a `TabControl` that includes `TabItems` whoes `Content`s are custom `UserControl`s.
Those controls are of the following form:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinition> 
        <ScrollViewer Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="scrollViewer11" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"></ScrollViewer>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto" Name="scrollViewer12" Width="Auto"  Margin="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"></ScrollViewer>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" Name="scrollViewer21" Width="Auto" Margin="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"></ScrollViewer>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto" Name="scrollViewer22" Width="Auto"  Margin="0"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"></ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The amount of rows and columns depends on the control used and ranges from a single cell in a 1x1 grid to 6 cells in a 3x2 grid (each contraining the `ScrollViewer`).

Now to my actual C# code. To each cell the user may add a `WriteableBitmap` where the code is organized as such:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<WorkSpace> WorkSpaceList = new List<WorkSpace>();
    private WorkSpace currentSpace = null;

    //one of the methods that adds to the TabControl, here a 2x2 grid:

    private void NewWorkspaceFour(WorkSpace ws)
    {
        WorkSpaceFour workSpaceFour = new WorkSpaceFour();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            WorkPlace wp = new WorkPlace();
            ws.workPlaceList.Add(wp);

            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    workSpaceFour.scrollViewer11.Content = wp.grid;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    workSpaceFour.scrollViewer12.Content = wp.grid;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    workSpaceFour.scrollViewer21.Content = wp.grid;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    workSpaceFour.scrollViewer22.Content = wp.grid;
                    break;
            }
        }

        ws.tabItem.Content = workSpace;
        tabControlImages.Items.Add(ws.tabItem);
    }

    //triggered in UI e.g. by moving a Slider
    private void NewSettings(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
         currentSpace.NewSettings((float)(e.NewValue));
    }

}

internal class WorkSpace
{
    internal delegate void NewSettingHandler(float e);

    internal List<WorkPlace> workPlaceList = new List<WorkPlace>();
    internal TabItem tabItem = new TabItem();
    internal WorkPlace currentPlace = null;

    internal NewSettingsHandler NewSettings;

    internal WorkSpace()
    {
        NewSettings += ChangeSettings;
    }

    internal void ChangeSettings(float newValue)
    {
        //do something small with newValue
        currentPlace.RecalculateImage();
    }

    //...more methods that would use "newValue" in a different way, thus the delegate
}

internal class WorkPlace
{
    internal WriteableBitmap bitmap;
    internal Image image = new Image {//settings};
    internal Grid grid = new Grid {//settings};
    internal Grid gridImage = new Grid {//settings};

    internal WorkPlace()
    {
        grid.Children.Add(gridImage);
        gridImage.Children.Add(image);
    }

    internal void RecalculateImage()
    {
        //some rather long calculations...

        bitmap.WritePixels(...,...,...,...);
        image.Source = bitmap;
    }
}
```

Through the program the user can change the tabs to change `currentSpace` and click on the cells to change the respective `currentPlace` both simply by change the reference i.e. `currentSpace = space`, where `space` refers to the `WorkSpace` that contains the new selected `TabItem`.

Now the issue is as follows. When a tab contains a simple 1x1 grid with an image in it and I move the slider, it runs very smoothly. When a tab contains a 3x2 grid and only a single cell of this grid contains a `WorkPlace` with a `bitmap` that is not `null` it works the same. However, when the 3x2 grid is completely filled with "painted" `bitmap`s and the slider is moved a noticable lag appears, even though only a single of the 6 images is recalculated redrawn. I don't see why this should be the case. It might have something to do with rendering or the object references but I don't know C# well enough to see and issues here.

Hopefully, the code is not too long (I have stripped it down as much as I could) and clear enough. If anything is not, please say so and I will update/add it. In a previous version of this program the UI was basically the same but the recalculation of the images was fairly different but I could never observe this problem.

Comment: how many pixels do your images have?

Comment: About 200,000. But it doesnt matter how big the Image is. I can add the same Image to every cell, the issue occurs when I update a single image in a grid with more Images in it.